# having XMLRPC-client and XMLRPC-server bundles in an OSGi environment triggers uses constraint violation due to split packages

Tags: java, osgi, xml-rpc, apache-karaf

I have a pair of Karaf OSGi environments that have 2-way communication using Apache XMLRPC. These used to work with Apache-XMLRPC 2.0.1, but I am upgrading this to Apache XMLRPC 3.1.3, which uses an entirely different architecture with separate xmlrpc-client, xmlrpc-server and xmrpc-common jars. Because I use OSGi, I need to use the Apache Servicemix Bundles for xmlrpc-client and xmrpc-server, which are both generated with the xmrpc-common code integrated. and this is where my problem is: OSGi is giving me errors during startup about split packages:

```
Error starting bundle 109: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] because it is exposed to package 'org.apache.xmlrpc.common' from resources org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)] and org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)]

Chain 2:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.server; uses:=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:61)
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:69)[36:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.execute(BundlesCommand.java:54)[36:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:274)[56:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error starting bundle 109: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] because it is exposed to package 'org.apache.xmlrpc.common' from resources org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)] and org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)]

Chain 2:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.server; uses:=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:66)[36:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.7]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] because it is exposed to package 'org.apache.xmlrpc.common' from resources org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)] and org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client [120](R 120.0)]

Chain 2:
  lib.util.xmlrpc [lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.xmlrpc.server; uses:=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.common
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server [119](R 119.0)] Unresolved requirements: [[lib.util.xmlrpc [109](R 109.11)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlrpc.server)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:38)[36:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.7]
        at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:64)[36:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.7]
        ... 12 more
```

This is my bnd_xml_rpc_bundle.bnd file:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: lib.util.xmlrpc
Bundle-Name: LIB XML-RPC bundle
Bundle-Version: 7.0.0
Private-Package: lib.util.xmlrpc
Export-Package: lib.util.xmlrpc


Import-Package: lib.util.logging,\
    lib.util.helpers,\
    lib.util.exceptions,\
    org.apache.commons.codec.*,\
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.*,\
    javax.*;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.*;resolution:=optional,\
    *
DynamicImport-Package: product.*
```

I have tried to add the below to the bnd file:

Require-Bundle: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-server, \
    org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlrpc-client

However, the only effect this had was that OSGi complains about a different package that's split. I have had errors about the base org.apache.xmlrpc package, about org.apache.xmlrpc.common (as found above), and about org.apache.xmlrpc.util.

I'm not sure how to fix this. According to the resources I found, the Require-Bundle statement is what's supposed to fix split packages, but I can't find that much information about it because the general consensus is "don't have split packages".

How do I fix this problem with a split package?

Comment: I suggest to open an issue in servicemix to fix this. I think the common part should live in its own bundle.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Acknowledged. I have created an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SM-4314